# get an error while decoding encrypted file

Tags: swift, encryption, jsondecoder, aes-gcm

I try to post the question with correction and a more clear intent:

this func **MyDecrypt** gives me error: *❌ Failed to decrypt file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0}
*

the goal of the whole code is to generate a seed, make a symmetric key, encode in base 64, create a folder, save the json in the folder, then zip it and encrypt it. Then, decrypt everything. I'm doing it, so I do not endorse some library, neither ask for them.

my issue is not related to third party libraries, but I think to the sequence I'm doing things.

UPDATE:
I cut the code so it is testable without the git. Shorter than this it is not possible

[Here](https://github.com/stark226/test_salvataggio_dati.git) you can find my repo.

here the pod file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'test' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for daCapo
   pod 'CryptoSwift', '~> 1.6.0'
 pod "MnemonicSwift"
  pod 'SSZipArchive'

end
```

here the main view controller, a lot of code but I cannot avoid to show what I'm doing while ENCRYPTING

```
import UIKit
import MnemonicSwift
import CryptoKit
import SSZipArchive
import MobileCoreServices


// A sample structure to encode
struct User: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let mnemonicString = "cattle swallow auction pistol orchard dilemma brain dynamic popular ready critic grief"
    let encodingModel = EncodingModel.shared
    let commonAppFolderForTheFileURL = FileManager.documentDirectoryURL
    let dummyUser = User(name: "obi-wan", age: 43)
    let fileName = "myJedi.json"
    let folderName = "myNewFolder"
    //Generate mnemonic and seed
    //let mnemonicString = try Mnemonic.generateMnemonic(strength: 128, language: .english)
    //print("Mnemonic: \(mnemonicString)")
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
//        MyEncrypt(mnemonicString: mnemonicString, user: dummyUser)
        
        MyDecrypt(mnemonicString: mnemonicString, folderName: folderName, fileName: fileName)
    }
    
    
    func MyEncrypt(mnemonicString: String, user: User) {
        

            do {
                //func generateSeedAndEncode64
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //Creates seed via Bip39, encodes in 64 bits
                //BIP39 section
                try Mnemonic.validate(mnemonic: mnemonicString)
                let deterministicSeedString = try Mnemonic.deterministicSeedString(from: mnemonicString, passphrase: "test", language: .english)
                //econding in base 64
                let simmetricKey = encodingModel.keyFromPassword(deterministicSeedString)
                let base64EncodedString = try encodingModel.encryptCodableObject(user, usingKey: simmetricKey)
                //mandiamo fuori: simmetricKey, base64EncodedString
                
                //func saveZipUserJson(user: String, fileName: String, folderName: String, symmetricKey: SymmetricKey
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //creates the folder for for storing json
                let folderURL = commonAppFolderForTheFileURL.appendingPathComponent(folderName, isDirectory: true)
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: folderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                
                // saving json in the folder
                let fileURL = folderURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                print("saveZipEncryptUserJson\nfileURL save:\n\(fileURL)\n")
                let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                let jsonData = try encoder.encode(user)
                let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
                try jsonString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                                
                // Creare il file zip da tutta la cartella
                let zipFileURL = commonAppFolderForTheFileURL.appendingPathComponent("\(folderName).zip") //myNewFolder.zip.encrypted
                SSZipArchive.createZipFile(atPath: zipFileURL.path, withContentsOfDirectory: folderURL.path)
                print("saveZipEncryptUserJson\n✅ File Zip saved at:\n\(zipFileURL)\n")
                //return : zipFileURL
                
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------

                ///crypting via AES
                let zipData = try Data(contentsOf: zipFileURL)
                let encryptedData = try AES.GCM.seal(zipData, using: simmetricKey)
                // Check if encryptedData.combined is not nil before unwrapping it
                guard let encryptedZipData = encryptedData.combined else {
                    throw NSError(domain: "EncryptionError", code: 2, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to create encrypted zip data"])
                }
                let encryptedZipFileURL = zipFileURL.appendingPathExtension("encrypted")
                // Write encrypted data to file
                try encryptedZipData.write(to: encryptedZipFileURL)
                //mandiamo fuori: encryptedZipFileURL per poter decriptare //URL(fileURLWithPath: zipFilePath)
//                controlliamoCheCiSiaIlFile(atUrl: encryptedZipFileURL)
//                controlloCheFileCruptatoEoriginaleSianoDiversi(originalDataUrl: zipFileURL, encryptedDataUrl: encryptedZipFileURL)
                
            } catch {
                print("❌ \(error.localizedDescription)")
                print("❌❌ \(error)")
            }
        
    }
    
    
    func MyDecrypt(mnemonicString: String, folderName: String, fileName: String) {
        do {
            // symmetri key from seed Mnemonic
            try Mnemonic.validate(mnemonic: mnemonicString)
            let deterministicSeedString = try Mnemonic.deterministicSeedString(from: mnemonicString, passphrase: "test", language: .english)
            let simmetricKey = encodingModel.keyFromPassword(deterministicSeedString)
            
            // recover crypted file
            let encryptedZipFileURL = commonAppFolderForTheFileURL.appendingPathComponent("\(folderName).zip.encrypted")
            
            // decode crypted zip file
            let encryptedData = try Data(contentsOf: encryptedZipFileURL)
            let sealedBox = try AES.GCM.SealedBox(combined: encryptedData)
            let decryptedData = try AES.GCM.open(sealedBox, using: simmetricKey)
            
            // folder for cleared data
            let decryptedFolderURL = commonAppFolderForTheFileURL.appendingPathComponent("\(folderName)_decrypted", isDirectory: true)
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: decryptedFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            
            let decryptedFileURL = decryptedFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            try decryptedData.write(to: decryptedFileURL)
//            print("✅ Decrypted file written to: \(decryptedFileURL)")
        } catch {
            print("❌ Failed to decrypt file: \(error)")
        }
    }

}

extension FileManager {
    static var documentDirectoryURL: URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory
    }
}

///this gives:
///❌ Failed to read JSON file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0}
func readJSONFile(fileURL: URL) throws -> Any {
    let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
    let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments)
    return jsonObject
}

///this gives
///❌ Failed to read JSON file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0}
func printJSONContent(fileURL: URL) {
    do {
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
            print("✅ JSON content:\n\(jsonObject)")
        } else if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
            print("✅ JSON content:\n\(jsonArray)")
        } else {
            print("❌ Invalid JSON format")
        }
    } catch {
        print("❌ Failed to read JSON file: \(error)")
    }
}





extension FileManager {
    static var documentDirectoryURL: URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory
    }
}

///this gives:
///❌ Failed to read JSON file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0}
func readJSONFile(fileURL: URL) throws -> Any {
    let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
    let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments)
    return jsonObject
}

///this gives
///❌ Failed to read JSON file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0}
func printJSONContent(fileURL: URL) {
    do {
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
            print("✅ JSON content:\n\(jsonObject)")
        } else if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
            print("✅ JSON content:\n\(jsonArray)")
        } else {
            print("❌ Invalid JSON format")
        }
    } catch {
        print("❌ Failed to read JSON file: \(error)")
    }
}
```

the code used for encryption

```
import Foundation
import CryptoKit

class EncodingModel {
    //from: https://fred.appelman.net/?p=119
    
    
    static let shared = EncodingModel()
    
    private init() {}
    
    
    /// Create an ecnryption key from a given password
    /// - Parameter password: The password that is used to generate the key
    func keyFromPassword(_ password: String) -> SymmetricKey {
        // Create a SHA256 hash from the provided password
        let hash = SHA256.hash(data: password.data(using: .utf8)!)
        // Convert the SHA256 to a string. This will be a 64 byte string
        let hashString = hash.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
        // Convert to 32 bytes
        let subString = String(hashString.prefix(32))
        // Convert the substring to data
        let keyData = subString.data(using: .utf8)!
        
        // Create the key use keyData as the seed
        return SymmetricKey(data: keyData)
    }
    
    
    
    /// Encrypt the given object that must be Codable and
    /// return the encrypted object as a base64 string
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - object: The object to encrypt
    ///   - key: The key to use for the encryption
    func encryptCodableObject<T: Codable>(_ object: T, usingKey key: SymmetricKey) throws -> String {
        // Convert to JSON in a Data record
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        let userData = try encoder.encode(object)
        
        // Encrypt the userData
        let encryptedData = try ChaChaPoly.seal(userData, using: key)
        
        // Convert the encryptedData to a base64 string which is the
        // format that it can be transported in
        return encryptedData.combined.base64EncodedString()
    }
    
    
    
    /// Decrypt a given string into a Codable object
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - type: The type of the resulting object
    ///   - string: The string to decrypt
    ///   - key: The key to use for the decryption
    func decryptStringToCodableOject<T: Codable>(_ type: T.Type, from string: String,
                                                 usingKey key: SymmetricKey) throws -> T {
        // Convert the base64 string into a Data object
        let data = Data(base64Encoded: string)!
        // Put the data in a sealed box
        let box = try ChaChaPoly.SealedBox(combined: data)
        // Extract the data from the sealedbox using the decryption key
        let decryptedData = try ChaChaPoly.open(box, using: key)
        // The decrypted block needed to be json decoded
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let object = try decoder.decode(type, from: decryptedData)
        // Return the new object
        return object
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: This is a repost of [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75671703/cannot-decrypt-data-in-swift). No need to edit the original and post a new one.

Comment: I'm about to delte the old one

Comment: In `saveZipUserJson(user: String, ...)` you are encoding a string (note user: String), 
`let jsonData = try encoder.encode(user)`, but in `unzipAndReadUserJson` you are decoding 
a "User", `let user = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: jsonData) `. This is where the 
decoding error comes from. Try `let user = try decoder.decode(String.self, from: jsonData) ` to get the `base64EncodedString`, decode this, 
then create a `User` from it.

Comment: You don’t need json encoding or decoding at all. To save you go User, encrypt to b64 string,  to data to save. Then to read you should  get Data, undo base64, decrypt, to User. JSON encoding is unnecessary.

Comment: You haven’t provided a Minimal Reproducible example and I don’t usually work with repos when dealing with SO questions. You need to reverse what you do in the generate seed method that is the issue with your code.

Comment: I cut the code so it is now Reproducible without the git. Shorter than this it is not possible. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In `retriveUser`, you unziped and decrypted the file,
but I believe it still has base64encoding data in it (judging by the print output).
From that basis, you could try the following approach,
where you decode the data from your file, first from base64 encoding to a `String`,
then to a `User`:

```
  func unzipAndReadUserJson(fileName: String, folderName: String) -> User? {
      
      let commonAppFolderForTheFileURL = FileManager.documentDirectoryURL
      
      do {
          // Creare la cartella temporanea per l'estrazione del file zip
          let tempFolderURL = commonAppFolderForTheFileURL
              .appendingPathComponent("temp", isDirectory: true)
              .deletingLastPathComponent()
          try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: tempFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
          
          // Estrarre il file zip nella cartella temporanea
          let zipFileURL = commonAppFolderForTheFileURL.appendingPathComponent("\(folderName).zip")
          let unzipResult = SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: zipFileURL.path, toDestination: tempFolderURL.path)
          guard unzipResult else {
              print("unzipAndReadUserJson - ❌ Errore durante l'unzip del file zip")
              return nil
          }
          print("unzipAndReadUserJson - ✅ file unzipped")
          
          // Leggere il file JSON estratto
          let folderURL = tempFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(folderName, isDirectory: true)
          let fileURL = folderURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
          //print("fileURL unzip:\n\(fileURL)")

          // <---------
          let theData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
          
          // convert theData into a string
          let b64String = String(data: theData, encoding: .utf8)!
          
          // decode the base64 string
          let b64Data = Data(base64Encoded: b64String)!
          let theString = String(data: b64Data, encoding: .utf8)!
          print("\n----> theString: \(theString)")
          
          // create a json data from the decoded base64 string
          let thisData = Data(theString.utf8)
          // decode the jsonData into a User
          let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: thisData)
          // <---------

          print("unzipAndReadUserJson - ✅ \(user)")
          
          return user
          
      } catch {
          print("unzipAndReadUserJson - ❌ \(error.localizedDescription)")
          return nil
      }
  }
```

Comment: testing your code I have let b64Data = Data(base64Encoded: b64String)!  with unwrapping error Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: There is no need for json encoding

Comment: yes, sorry, my bad, I should **never** use forced unwrapping. Use `if let  ...{...}`

Comment: no sorry at all, I added a guard let b64Data = Data(base64Encoded: b64String) else { print("unzipAndReadUserJson - ❌ b64Data è nil") return nil } just replayed because there was that nil value and I still cannot solve the issue

Comment: could you add a few `prints`, like:  `print("\n----> theData: \(theData)")` and `print("\n----> b64String: \(b64String)")` and show us what they print.

Comment: There is just too much code that I can't compiled or run. Cut the code down to just replicating your issue.
Show a minimal reproducible code, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  then it will be easier for everyone to help.

Comment: I cut the code so it is now Reproducible without the git. Shorter than this it is not possible. Hope it helps.